# Ruby on Rails using whitelist and blacklists to allow current user to see page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whitelist, blacklist

basically I want to see if the user has added any blacklist_users or whitelist_users and then allow or disallow them according to that but I am having trouble figuring out the code properly:(us_id is basically user_id)

Relationship:
  Blacklist_user model:

```
belongs_to :b_page
```

Whitelist_user model:

```
 belongs_to :b_page
```

B_page model:

```
   has_many :whitelist_user
   has_many :blacklist_user
```

controller:

```
if !(@b_page.whitelist_user.empty?)
   @whitelist_users = @b_page.whitelist_user.map(&:us_id)
   @whitelist_users.push(@b_page.user.id)
 else
   @whitelist_users = []
 end    
 if !(@b_page.blacklist_user.empty?)
   @blacklist_users = @b_page.blacklist_user.map(&:us_id)
  else
   @b_page.blacklist_user = []
   @blacklist_users = @b_page.blacklist_user.map(&:us_id)
 end
```

views:

```
<% if ((!(@whitelist_users.empty?)) && @whitelist_users.include?(current_user.id)) || ((!(@blacklist_users.empty?)) && @blacklist_users.exclude?(current_user.id)) %>
<!-- show bpage -->


<% elsif ! ((!((@whitelist_users.empty?)) && @whitelist_users.include?(current_user.id)) || ((!(@blacklist_users.empty?)) && @blacklist_users.exclude?(current_user.id)))%>
<!-- user not allowed-->
<% else %>
<!-- show bpage-->
<% end %>
```

but when I sign in as the @b_page.user i get the (btw I use devise)
is there any better way to implement this, instead of complicating it even more

Answer (score 0):

If they're separate models, then you can do this in your controller action. Devise comes with a method, user_signed_in?, which will tell you if a user is signed in or not. In your case:

```
blacklist_user_signed_in?
whitelist_user_signed_in?
```

Then in your controller action for showing the page:

```
if blacklist_user_signed_in?
  return redirect_to root_path,
         notice: 'You are not alllowed to access this part of the site'
end
```

This assumes your models are called blacklist_user and whitelist_user. If they simply have attributes and are the same model, you can do:

```
 current_user.blacklisted?
```

and in your user model

```
def blacklisted?
  blacklist
end
```

Once more that assumes you have an attribute called 'blacklist' in your 'user' model.

Comment: that requires blacklist_users and whitelist_users to be related to the users model but they are only related to the b_page model

Comment: plus what I want is to use the whitelist and the blacklist together